# Is there a "collected together" explanation of the threading and atomic support in C11?

Tags: c, threading

I want to start using some of the atomic locking support in [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#C11) to speed up some existing multi-threaded code, but I'm struggling to find a reasonably concise yet complete description of the various concepts and functions. For example I'm still a bit hazy about the various memory order concepts.

I there an authoritative document anywhere? Preferably with examples, but I can live without those so long as it is written in plain English and not in "only-Linus-could-understand-this" speak!

I think I've established that there isn't a book, but surely there must be an online resource?

My skill level is pretty good at traditional ANSI C, quite a lot of experience with Posix and Windows native threads, but I don't speak assembler I'm afraid.

Anyway thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Sorry. Questions about programming are [off-topic here on Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Additionally, seeking learning material recommendation is also off-topic.

Comment: suggest asking this question on stackoverflow.com